# How to access database running for local profile in a shared environment?

Tags: linux, postgresql, shared-hosting

I'm not the root of a linux shared server. 
I have installed postgres for my local profile (http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/06/installing-postgresql-without-root.html)

I'm running a python code on the same server to access that database.

What should I give my URL as in my python code:
dbURL =postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/myDb

OR should I add 
export PATH=$HOME/postgres/bin/:$PATH in my .bashrc file

I checked from terminal, myDb is on localhost:5432 postgres server.
Everything is working fine when I interact with my database from terminal.

Sorry, I'm not able to get why my code is not able to connect to this db. 
PS: Everything is fine from code side as well (was running perfectly on local machine)

Comment: do you get a connection error?

Comment: Yes,

could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: your username is postgres and password is root yes?

Comment: yes username is postgres, password is root

Comment: paste the terminal command that connects

Comment: [ak5146@log-0 postgres]$ ~/postgres/bin/psql -U postgres mydb -p 5432 -h localhost -W root
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "root" ignored
Password for user ak5146:
psql (9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=#

Comment: As you can see I am using path as ~/postgres/bin/psql , which is my local directory.
Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: there is different casing in your database name between the terminal command and connection string, try connection string: `postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/mydb`

if that doesnt work try no password.

Comment: for no password, is this valid ?
postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/mydb

Btw, thanks @chris for getting back :)

Comment: yes i think that would send a null password.  are the computer where you connect with the connection string and the computer you connect to from the terminal the same machine?

Comment: yes, it is.....